# Check if Computer supports PSE Assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

I want check that CPU have support PSE. I found in Intel doc that PSE is on BIT 3 in `EDX` Register.

I have code for PAE:

```
pae:
    mov eax,1
    cpuid
    test EDX, 000000020h
    jnz is_pae
    jmp name
```

In Intel doc is that PAE is on BIT 6 in `EDX` Register. Why in code is 000000020h and what value use to check PSE.

Comment: This requires a basic understanding of bits and hex formats. Beyond that though, there's not really enough left for it to be a good question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `PAE` code is wrong - it's testing `MSR`, not `PAE`. It should be:

```
test EDX, 000000040h  ; test PAE (bit 6)
```

Similarly for PSE it would be:

```
test EDX, 000000008h  ; test PSE (bit 3)
```